# 'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode'

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core

I want to convert a list of strings to a javascript array in my view, and I've found the below suggestion in a few places on the internet:

```
@model IEnumerable<DSSTools.Models.Box.BoxWhiteListUser>

@{
    var boxManager = new DSSTools.Managers.BoxManager();
    var allusers = boxManager.GetAllUsersAsync().Result.Entries.ToList().Select(u => u.Login);
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var sourcearray = null;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var arr = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@allusers))');
        });
    </script>
}
```

However, I just get an annoying

> 'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How is this possible?

I also tried simply calling

```
var arr = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(allusers)');
```

But then I get this error in the console

```
VM189:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (whitelist:107)
    at fire (jquery.js:3182)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3312)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3531)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3547)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to do what I needed with

```
sourcearray = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(allusers))');
```

Comment: I think you could drop the JSON.parse if you remove the quotes. The following should work `sourcearray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(allusers));`

Answer (score 10):

Your answer can be simplified from:

```
sourcearray = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(allusers))');
```

To:

```
sourcearray = @Json.Serialize(allusers);
```

Explanation:

1. `Json.Serialize()` returns `IHtmlContent`, which does not need to be wrapped inside `@Html.Raw()` to preserve special characters.
2. The text returned by `@Json.Serialize()` is already valid javascript object syntax.  You're better off using it as is, rather than converting it to a string by wrapping it in quotes and then converting that string to an object via `JSON.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Json.Serialize` did not work for me since it changed all properties to camelCase and I need them i PascalCase. Kinda weird choice of them to change the casing when serializing, but anyway.

Part of the reason for that is that we use `Newtonsoft.Json` along with `Json.Encode` and the JavaScripts needs to be able to handle both.

So to fix this was fairly simple using the following: `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))`